# ¿Cómo corregir este código para manipular un stack?

Tags: javascript, estructuras-de-datos, stack

Ya tengo este ejercicio casi listo pero hay uno de los test que me piden que no lo entiendo ya que me pide Debe crear un stack y agregar o quitar elementos según la secuencia recibida y retornar el stack

```
    function crearStack(palabra) {
        let stack = [];
    
        if (palabra.length === 0) {
            return false
        }
        introducir el código aquí
        for (let i = 0; i < palabra.length; i++) {
            {
                if (palabra[i] === "*") {
                    if (stack.length === 0) return "Stack vacío";
                    stack.pop()
                } else {
                    stack.push(palabra[i])
                }
            }
        }
        return stack ;
        
    }
```

** Debe crear un stack y agregar o quitar elementos según la secuencia recibida y retonar el stack**
Me falta esto solamente pero no se no veo que me falta en el codigo para que me pueda pasar como valido

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Supongo que la línea `introducir el código aquí` no es parte de tu código :)  Con qué dato se corre la prueba? Por qué la validación contra `*` antes del pop? Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! yo tampoco entiendo que te piden, pero esto: return stack = new Stack; esta mal...

Comment: listo gracias por tu comentario soy nuevo y estoy aprendiendo tanto en js como preguntar por aquí pero tomare en cuenta tu comentario para futuras

Comment: Puedes poner la consigna entera?